# What is significance of "!" operator in Apache struts2/ ONGL expression?

Tags: struts2, operators, ognl

I'm working on Apache Struts 2 web application development. I wanted to use `!` operator in Struts2 application.

Could you please tell me what is the significance of the `!` operator in  Apache struts2/ OGNL expression?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: You want to use it, but you're asking what it is? Why do you want to use it if you don't know its "significance"?

Answer (score 0):

As in the majority of the programming languages, 
in OGNL the *Bang* operator (`!`) represents the **Logical Not**.

```xml
<s:if test="!foo.isEmpty()">
```

means

> *"if foo is **not** empty"*.

---

NOTE: if, instead, you're referring to the bang sign put in front of the method name when calling an action, like:

```
http://foo.com/bar/myAction!myMethod.action
```

(then pure old Struts2, no OGNL involved), that is called DMI (Dynamic Method Invocation), and is deprecated. Do not use it.